# DataTables: With filter input boxes at the top of each column: I need Narrow Column Widths for some columns

Tags: datatables

Problem: DataTables 1.10.4: I need to reduce the width of some of the column filter input boxes in my table.

I am using jquery.dataTables.css and jquery.dataTables.js as provided with the exception of adding some colour and border styling to the css file.

My table will eventually have more than 100 rows and there are 15 columns. Here is a link http://www.stockportwalkers.org.uk/development/walking_routes_w_datatables.html

I would like to make the widths of some of the column filter input boxes much narrower. For example the data in one of the columns is a single character. From tests I have done it seems to me that the minimum width of the input box is fixed preventing narrower columns. This means that some of my columns are far too wide for the data and my table is too wide to be easily manageable.

If I remove the filter input boxes at the top of each column the columns resize themselves nicely, but the column filters are essential.

I have seen a lot of posts for similar problems but nothing I have tried has changed the column widths. I have tried defining the columns to fixed widths using css width, js aocolumns, column, columndef. I have set "bAutoWidth": false. Nothing has helped. I have been unable to find where the column filter input box is sized.

I have been struggling with this for a while and would very much appreciate a solution.  Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this column search plugin for DataTables that you can include which may help your formatting issue.  You don't have to worry about trying to insert the columns yourself or adding in the keyup event.  It is all handled for you.  It also works with the responsive tables to hide the search field if the column drops off.

https://github.com/zepernick/Plugins/tree/master/features/columnSearchField

Directions for the plugin can be found [here](https://github.com/zepernick/Plugins/blob/master/features/columnSearchField/dataTables.colsearch.md)

Here is an example usage of the plugin:

```
var dt = $("#mytable").DataTable();
//using defaults
new $.fn.dataTable.DtServerColSearch(dt);
//OR 
new $.fn.dataTable.DtServerColSearch(dt, {
    placement: "foot",
    placeholders: false,
    ....
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use this plugin but some of my columns are still too wide. With the filter input box present I am unable to use width to reduce the size of the column.

Comment: It looks like you usage comment got cut off.  Do you have a link to see the new updates you made to the table?

Comment: Maybe it is something wrong with my css? Here is the table styling:
<table id="routes_table" class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
so theortically I should be able to style the <th> with width

I have tried setting table width to 6000px say which pruduces evenly sized wider column but am still unable to persuade a column to be narrower or wider. The columns stay exactly the same width. I am able to make a col wider with padding but as I need narrower columns this doesn't help.

Comment: Yes. I will do that in about an hour. Sorry but I am not in a position to do it straight away

Comment: I would take the width and cellpacing attributes off.  In your current table, I also see that you have lots of hard spaces in the table data.  For example: <td>4.5
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>  Not sure what that might be doing.

Comment: http://www.stockportwalkers.org.uk/development/walking_routes_w_datatables.html  This is the link with the new filter boxes. As you can see the original almost invisible sort icons are still in the original column headers.  Hard spaces? I wanted the numbers to be right justified but centered in the column. I have it on my to do list to find a better solution but if the columns can be reduced in width the hard spaces won't be needed. I also put some padding in the Walk Desc column to prevent the row becoming too deep. Again, if if I can use width that will be better.  Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to modify the widths of the columns using the DataTable API.  http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width   `{
  "columnDefs": [
    { "width": "20%", "targets": 0 }
  ]
}` You can use the "targets" property to specify which column index to apply the width to, otherwise you have to set the specific width for every one.

Comment: Unfortunately, using columnDefs made no difference to the column widths. Is it possible to reduce the width of the column filter input boxes?

Comment: You could throw this in your stylesheet if you are ok with them being all the same width: `tr.dataTable_colSearchBar input{ width: 50% } or you could do a fixed pixel on the width if you wanted to.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is looking a lot better!  The very last touch is to center the column filter input boxes.  How can I do this?